# Xcode run out of memory

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and I'm trying to read a file (it consists of 100_000 pairs of integers) in Swift Playground.
File looks next:

> 100000
>  154 746
>  0 147
>  4 9000
>  1876 19
>  2345
>   467
>  5 6244
>  1 7532
>  .......

The first element is N (total number of pairs), followed by those pairs.

The way I'm reading file is next:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var N = Int ()
var l = [UInt16] ()
var r = [UInt16] ()

let fileName = "request2"

guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") else { fatalError("Can't get \(fileName).txt")
}

do {
    let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
    let contentsInStringArray = contents.components(separatedBy: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    var i = 0
    var isNRead = false

    for element in contentsInStringArray {
        guard !element.isEmpty else {
            continue
        }

        if !isNRead {
            N = Int(element) ?? 0
            isNRead = true
            continue
        }

        let temp = UInt16(element) ?? 0
        if i % 2 == 0 {
            l.append(temp)
        } else {
            r.append(temp)
        }
        i += 1
    }
} catch _ {
    fatalError("Can't get contents of \(fileName).txt")
}
```

The reading of the file is dramatically slow! 
And as a result I got Xcode run out of memory.

How to optimise the reading?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should start by creating a proper project for this rather than using the playground. And it might be better to read the file line by line

Comment: check https://forums.swift.org/t/read-text-file-line-by-line/28852

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I'm not sure about separate project just for few sample functions. I hope that playground could be enough 

Comment: You can't expect the same performance from running your code in a playground and setting up a command-line app project for instance is trivial.

Comment: If you write a real project, you can use Instruments to find out _what_ is slow and _what_ is using up memory. You can't debug a playground. You are tying your own hands and then complaining that your hands are tied. :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, thanks a lot for help! command-line app solves that in a second 